# Why is there no "the" before this sentence?

Tags: articles

I read a sentence from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand:

> **Demand** for a specific item is a function of an item's perceived necessity, price, perceived quality, convenience, available alternatives, purchasers' disposable income and tastes, and many other factors.

Why is it not "The demand for a specific item..."? I have seen phrases like "the quantity of a good".

> Demand is **the quantity of a good** that consumers are willing and able to purchase at various prices during a given period of time.

Are both forms correct? If so, what is the difference between with the and without the?

Does “the” often refer to the word immediately after it or does it sometimes refer to the phrase after it, not the single word? What does “the” do in “the construction of a new house” and “ the theory of relativity”?

Comment: To my ear, both forms are correct, and there is no difference in meaning in that context.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty How is there no change of meaning when "the" is used? Can you please provide some other examples?

Comment: Well if you want other examples you could insert _the_ before _available_ or _purchasers'_ in that sentence without change of meaning.

Comment: How about in this sentence: "If the demand curve is linear, then it has the form: p = a - b*q, where p is the price of the good and q is the quantity demanded." Can I rewrite the sentence like "If the demand curve is linear, then it has the form: p = a - b*q, where p is price of the good and q is demand." The rewrited sentence looks flat wrong to me though.

Comment: Can I also write the second sentence as "Demand is quantity of a good that consumers are willing and able to purchase at various prices during a given period of time."

Comment: lexico [defines](https://www.lexico.com/definition/demand) it as a mass noun meaning *"The desire of consumers, clients, employers, etc. for a particular commodity, service, or other item"*

Comment: @AndrewTobilko When used with "for a good", should there be a "the" like "the color of a product. Or is "color of a product" correct? How about "I like the color of his eyes" and "I like color of his eyes".

Comment: if it's used as a mass noun (note that some arguments of the demand function are also mass nouns - necessity, quality, convenience, willingness), then [English uses no article before it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article).

Comment: @TFR the colour of his eyes/a product... but it's a bit different... I think here one should parse it as a *general* function definition (as in `demand(item)=function(item.necessity, item.quality, ...)`) where "for a specific item" doesn't set up the context, but is merely a function argument - [I am not a native, might be very off]

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Can you please explain it in simpler terms? And what about sentences like “Length of an object is how long the object is,” versus “The length of an object is how long the object is.”